# What does the question mark mean in js?

Tags: javascript

Guys so I'm new to javascript, I'm trying to do simple things and I found this piece of code for changing divs(which i named k) color when clicking it but I don't really understand what is it I know few things but one thing I can't find is that question mark. Can someone explain what is it and what it does. Thank you

```js
var x = document.getElementById("k"),
    change = false;
    
x.onclick = function() {
  change = !change;
  x.style.background = change? "red": "lime";
}
x.style.background = "lime";
```

Comment: Research ternary operator

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is a ternary operator. It's as if you are doing it like this:

```
if(change===true){
x.style.background = "red"
}else{
x.style.background = "lime"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That is the conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator